# Slow SQL Server response / timeout locally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a weird issue, which I'm hoping someone can shed some light on. I'm running SQL Server 2019 locally with several C# / ASP.NET MVC applications running in IIS on a Core I7 processor with 16gb RAM.

Periodically I experience SQL Server running really slowly and/or timing out. I'm 99% sure it's a SQL issue, as when using SQL Server Management Studio, even refreshing the list of databases or trying to browse the tables of a database can be very slow/never complete.

My solution has been to restart my machine, which does resolve the issue, however this is a pain and would be good to try and understand what the underlying issue is. It feels like SQL Server is maxing out its memory or something isn't letting go of a service/resource.

Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Comment: Presumably there is another big query running at the same time. try `sp_whoisactive` https://whoisactive.com/ and other tools to find out what's going on. This question is not answerable without further debugging details

Comment: Thanks, will try running that query next time it happens

Comment: You can also open Activity Monitor in SQL Management Studio, it displays some nice stats and also refreshes them from time to time. I never close it personally :)

Comment: Have you opened Resource Monitor when the slowdowns happen to see whether the impacts are CPU usage, Disk I/O, Network I/O and/or Memory? And whether the cause is actually SQL Server itself or some other process(es) impacting it?